# Cannot open pdf in SharePoint 2013- 'System.ArgumentException'

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, pdf, powerpoint

We migrated content from Moss 2007 to SharePoint 2013 using DB attach detach method. Everything is working fine so far. But we are not able to open Pdf/PowerPoint files from the document library. When we click on the pdf it is throwing an exception.

> Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.
>   Parameter name: encodedValue

We changed the "Browser File Handler" settings on the web app server from "Strict" to "Permissive", same error exists.

Comment: did you migrate from 07 to 10 to 13? Sounds like a huge bug, or something went wrong with the migration of documents.

Comment: Yes we did it from 07 to 10 to 13.